# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '...'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is probably one of the common questions related to SQL however I am having hard time figuring out what is the issue.

My current code is giving an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Incorrect syntax near '...'.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LTEST] (
    [Id]       INT  NOT NULL,
    [YRNRO]    INT  NULL,
    [HAKUNIMI] TEXT NULL,
    [NIMIA]    TEXT NULL,
    [NIMIB]    TEXT NULL,
    [KAYNTIOS] TEXT NULL,
    [POSTIOS]  TEXT NULL,
    [POSTINRO] TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

C#:

```
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnection1 = new OdbcConnection(connectionString1))
        {
            dbConnection1.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter dadapter1 = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            dadapter1.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryString1, dbConnection1);

            dadapter1.Fill(t1);

            SqlConnection tempDbConnection = new SqlConnection();
            tempDbConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            tempDbConnection.Open();

            string tempSql = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < t1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                tempSql = "INSERT INTO LTEST (YRNRO,HAKUNIMI,NIMIA,NIMIB,KAYNTIOS,POSTIOS,POSTINRO) VALUES ('"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["YRNRO"].ToString().Trim() + ",'"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["NIMIA"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["NIMIB"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["KAYNTIOS"].ToString().Trim() + "',"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["POSTIOS"].ToString().Trim() + "',"
                            + t1.Rows[i]["POSTINRO"].ToString().Trim() + ");'";
                SqlCommand tempCommand = new SqlCommand(tempSql, tempDbConnection);
                tempCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have also had a problem with path, it should be: `C:\Users\...\source\repos\...\...\CustomerDatabase.mdf`

Comment: **use parameters!** not only will it prevent you from _ever_ having problems like this again while potentially increasing performance, it also protects your database from **SQL injection attacks** (there is NO reason NOT to use parameters, ever, except for demonstrating how great parameters are)

Comment: Yep, parametrise your query, and this error can't even happen, and it secures your application. Double winner.

Comment: The error message doesn't stop after "near", instead, just after that, the relevant portion is shown. In your case, it's a missing single quote, but don't do this as others have already said. This will break when user input contains a single quote, or allows the user to perform SQL injection.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of tempSql at runtime? I wholeheartedly second what Franz says but it is impossible to see what that code will produce just by looking at it.

Comment: @Crowcoder _"it is impossible to see what that code will produce just by looking at it"_ - it's what we do on this site on a daily basis.

Comment: Not impossible, but hard. Several quotes are missing, but yeah, don't do it this way in the first place.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the tip. I did not know everyone had OP's database except me.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am just learning, this is test connection with test data. Here is no risk for hacking as it is on my local computer and operated locally. However it is better to learn it the right way directly as you say. I have been trying this example as well, maybe I had to be going with this solution from the start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Since you are interested in learning, I'll also mention that you are mixing ODBC and SqlClient. IMO you should just stick with SqlClient. Lastly, `TEXT` fields are most likely not what you want. That is for large object data and is actually deprecated. You probably want nvarchar or varchar.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am trying to get data from ODBC and paste it to Local SQL database to perform more actions locally later. I have went trough some websites and understood that 1) I need to import data from ODBC to datatable 2) I need to export data from datatable to Local SQL. That is what I am trying to do here. Found this and tried to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520142/c-sharp-insert-data-from-datatable-to-sql-server-database

Comment: @hatman ok, I see. Then disregard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, better try something like this:

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

string tempSql = "INSERT INTO LTEST (YRNRO,HAKUNIMI,NIMIA,NIMIB,KAYNTIOS,POSTIOS,POSTINRO) VALUES (@YRNRO, @HAKUNIMI, @NIMIA, @NIMIB, @KAYNTIOS, @POSTIOS, @POSTINRO)"
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionText))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@YRNRO", SqlDbType.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@HAKUNIMI", SqlDbType.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@NIMIA", SqlDbType.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@NIMIB", SqlDbType.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@KAYNTIOS", SqlDbType.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@POSTIOS", SqlDbType.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@POSTINRO", SqlDbType.Text);

    connection.Open();  
    for (int i = 0; i < t1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        command.Parameters["@YRNRO"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["YRNRO"].ToString().Trim();
        command.Parameters["@HAKUNIMI"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["@HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim();
        command.Parameters["@NIMIA"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["@HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim();
        command.Parameters["@NIMIB"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["@HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim();
        command.Parameters["@KAYNTIOS"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["@HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim();
        command.Parameters["@POSTIOS"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["@HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim();
        command.Parameters["@POSTINRO"].Value = t1.Rows[i]["@HAKUNIMI"].ToString().Trim();

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I guess it should be `SqlDbType.Text` as String is not supported for SqlDbType. As I am pasting data from datatable to SQL, how to male it read from datatable in your solution?

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, of course. What you could do is loop over the rows and update the parameter values or use something like SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you have a missing single quote on this line:

```
 + t1.Rows[i]["YRNRO"].ToString().Trim() + ",'"
//change to
 + t1.Rows[i]["YRNRO"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
```

But as a responsible senior developer, I MUST tell you to either use parameterised SQL, or wrap your script in a stored procedure and pass it parameters.

And maybe off topic, but to speed up execution, generate a bulk SQL script, and then execute all at once instead of inside a foreach loop.